# What does "dislike the result" mean in Memory of a Thousand Lifetimes?

Tags: dnd-4e, races, racial-traits

Pardon if this is a basic question; there are only 5 threads on this forum regarding the ability in mind, and none of them actually explain how it works.

Looking through the PHB2, I see the Deva Racial Power *Memory of a Thousand Lifetimes* has its trigger state the following:

> You make an attack roll, a saving throw, a skill check, or an ability check and dislike the result

Below that is the Effect and some flavor text, but nothing further explaining this. Specifically, what does it mean to "dislike the result?" That's a difficult term to search here or on Google, as it more or less just comes up with hatemail for 4e.

Comment: I've edited your question title to be more specific to the question you're asking. Welcome to RPG.SE!

Comment: I see, still getting used to the differences between this community and that of Stack Overflow. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### It means that you want to change it.

All "dislike the result" means in this context is that you have made a roll, and you want to use your ability to increase it. It means that any roll, at any time, can get a Memory of a Thousand Lifetimes added to it. If you roll, say, a 5 on an attack, and you think that's just a bit too low to hit the opponent, you can add 1d6 to that attack without spending an action.

Generally speaking, unless a term is defined as a specific game term somewhere, rules text means what it says in plain English. In this case, it means that you can use this power any time you want to after making one of the specified roll types.

Comment: Thank you! This is a wonderful answer that explained the term, gave a proper example, and gave insight as to its meaning. Perfect!